# Python regex group matches shows extra empty string

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I want to get the date followed by `DATE FILLED` and `REFILL` from my text. Ordering of `DATE FILLED` or `REFILL` is not fixed. And date pattern can be:

```
6/23/20
6-23-20
```

My Python scripts is:

```py
expiration_date_regex = re.compile(r"(USE\s+BY.*(?P<expiration>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}))|(DATE\s+FILLED.*(?P<date_filled>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4}))", re.M)
find_matches(expiration_date_regex, text)

def find_matches(regex, text):
    matches = regex.findall(text)
    for match in matches:
        print(match)
```

My text is:

```
CVS pharmacy
713-217 HsonSt
OTY: 90
REFILL 0 Refills
PRSCBN. A Beil
DATE FILLED 6/23/20
USE BY. 6/23/21
RPH Bill Liu
MFR AUROBINDO PHARM
ST DEA BC2236645
This is a WHITE
REDTME
```

But I'm getting output something like this, output is almost reasonable but I don't understand what do those first two empty strings means in the first tuple? same goes for last two string of the second tuple. It looks something like bitmask:

```
('', '', 'DATE FILLED 6/23/20', '6/23/20')
('USE BY. 6/23/21', '6/23/21', '', '')
```

Comment: Why not use simpler: `(USE\s+BY|DATE\s+FILLED).*(?P<date>\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{2,4})`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava your comment gives a solution. I had few question how can I handle if Use by and date fill is different date pattern? Is it better to use a single regex with group or write different for each? My use case is I'm getting those texts from an OCR and then finding my required patterns. Sometimes I may get Dat Fill instead of Date Filled

Comment: Or may be: `(?i)(USE\s+BY|DATE\s+FILL(?:ED)?).*(?P<date>\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2,4})`

Comment: Thanks again @anubhava it worked. Hope to read your book soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer so that solution is easy to find for future visitors.

You may use this regex:

```sh
(?i)(USE\s+BY|DATE\s+FILL(?:ED)?).*(?P<date>\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2,4})
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ccmqEL/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?i)`: Enable ignore case mode
- `(USE\s+BY|DATE\s+FILL(?:ED)?)`: Match `USE BY` or `DATE FILLED` or `DATE FILL`
- `.*`: Match 0 or more of any characters
- `(?P<date>\d{1,2}[-/]\d{1,2}[-/]\d{2,4})`: Match a date string using `/` or `-` as delimiter